# NodeJS ENOTFOUND db when connecting to MySQL container on docker

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to connect From Node.js on Localhost to MySQL instance running on docker using docker-compose.

Node.js gives me this error: `ENOTFOUND db`, Full error message bellow.

```sh
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
Application Name: RESTFull API - Development
Environment: development
Server is listening on port 3000
getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND db # <------------ Error here
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Here is docker-compose.yml that contains MySQL and adminer services.

```yaml
## docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'nodejs-restfull-api-development'
    expose:
      - 3306
    volumes:
      - db-config:/etc/mysql
      - db-data:/var/lib/mysql

  adminer:
    image: adminer:latest
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      ADMINER_DEFAULT_DB_DRIVER: mysql
      ADMINER_DEFAULT_DB_HOST: db
      ADMINER_DESIGN: nette
      ADMINER_PLUGINS: tables-filter tinymce
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"

volumes:
  db-config:
  db-data:
```

Here is my node.js database connection config.

```js
const database = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'db',
  user: config.get('db.user'),
  password: config.get('db.password'),
  database: config.get('db.database'),
  port: config.get('db.port'),
  connectTimeout: config.get('db.connectTimeout')
});

database.connect(err => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
    process.exit(1);
  } else {
    console.log('Connected to database');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't tell us, but I assume your Node app is running on the host and not in a container? If that's the case, then you need to expose the MySQL port to the host, so it's reachable. You also need to use `localhost` as the hostname in your configuration.

Expose the port by changing the database part of your docker-compose file to

```
  db:
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'nodejs-restfull-api-development'
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - db-config:/etc/mysql
      - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
```

And change your Node configuration to

```
const database = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: config.get('db.user'),
  password: config.get('db.password'),
  database: config.get('db.database'),
  port: config.get('db.port'),
  connectTimeout: config.get('db.connectTimeout')
});
```